# Preorder traversal of ternary tree

Tags: java, tree-traversal, preorder, ternary-tree

I need to perform a preorder traversal of a ternary tree. I'm familiar with this traversal on a binary tree, such as:

```
public void preorder(){

   System.out.println(data); 
   if (left != null)
      left.preorder();
   if (right != null)
      right.preorder();
}
```

This traverses in the order Root, Left, Right. I am confused as to how to do this with a middle child node added. If anyone could explain this that would be great. thanks

Comment: wouldn't you just do a recursive call on the middle in between left and right?

Comment: Thats what I was thinking but I wasn't sure if that was definitely the right syntax or not. I was just looking for a confirmation

Comment: I think that's it.  `if (middle) middle.preorder();` after the left, before the right.

Comment: Yeah that sounds right to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General preorder traversal of n-ary tree goes as follows:

- Traverse the node itself
- If exists, traverse child<sub>0</sub>
- If exists, traverse child<sub>1</sub>
- ...
- If exists, traverse child<sub>n</sub>

Binary tree happens to have only child<sub>0</sub> (left) and child<sub>1</sub> (right), but ternary tree also has a middle. So your traversal would have an extra statement between traversing the left and the right subtree:

```
if (middle != null)
    middle.preorder();
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks for your help

Comment: @NickCastello You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer and are not looking for further help, consider accepting the answer by clicking the gray check box next to it (will become visible in 4 minutes). This would let other site visitors know that your problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse middle node between left and right node

```
public void preOrder(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(" " + node.data);
    preOrder(node.left);
    preOrder(node.middle);
    preOrder(node.right);
}
```